# Get id from URL on alias in vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have one route which should support 2 different URLs - `/settings/:code` and `/settings`:

```
{
    path: '/settings',
    alias: '/settings/:code',
    name: 'settings',
    component: settings
},
```

It is working correctly in my SPA when I go to URL `localhost:8080/settings` and `localhost:8080/settings/123` in both way it's hitting settings component.

How ever when I try to get this `:code` like this:

```
resetCode: this.$route.params.code,
```

from url it is always undefined even when I'm on `localhost:8080/settings/123`.

When I turn alias and path the other way around so it's:

```
{
    alias: '/settings',
    path: '/settings/:code',
    name: 'settings',
    component: settings
},
```

then my :code is correct, I mean it's 123 when I go to URL `localhost:8080/settings/123` but in this case it's not displaying settings component when I go to url `localhost:8080/settings`.

So either way is bad, how I can fix it?

Comment: Can this even be done with one route? I've always split these into distinct routes with distinct components.

Comment: As answer shows it can be done and in some cases it would be hilarious to have 2 components for that because you would need to have code redundant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how `alias` works. You can specify url alias with different names but not with url parameters.

```
path: '/settings'
alias: '/settings/:code' // incorrect
alias: '/settingsAlias' // correct (different path name)

path: '/settings/:code'
alias: '/settings' // incorrect ( param is missing )
alias: '/settingsAlias/:code' // correct
alias: '/settingsAlias/:codeAlias // correct
```

Also, the `@Thomas Kleßen` answer seems to be working fine for you. But this is not why child routes are created for.

```
path: '/settings',
component: settings,
children: [
  {
    path: ':code' // ( incorrect usage ) how is this children?
  }
]
```

Child routes should follow with a slash `/` (and not just `/:param` but `/pathname` ). If you use as preceding example, then you're just doing a trick with the router.

Then, what is the correct way of using it?

Well, you can **define an optional paramter**:

```
path: '/settings/:code?' // using ? defines param as optional
```

So, now you can hit `'/settings'` or `'/settings/123'` in the url.

Comment: Thank you this optional parameter is working. So previous answer was just a trick/hack and this is real solution in vue way, how vue developers would do if they use their framework so I change accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{
    name: 'settings',
    path: '/settings',
    component: settings,
    children: [
      {
        name: 'settings_code',
        path: ':code',
        component: settings
      }
    ]
}
```

It is untested, but i think because your alias and path match the same path your problem occurs.
That's why i suggest to try it with a child-route.

Comment: Working like a charm, nice!